# Web::Query and data extraction

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I had a problem with scraping info from a web page, which was solved by someone, but i would also like to get the data from that structure and put it into normal string variables, i commented saying this and was told to create a new question, so here it is!

code:

```
use Web::Query 'wq';
my $football_matches = wq($mech->content)
    ->find('tr.match')
    ->map(sub {
        my (undef, $e) = @_;
        return 'v' eq $e->find('td.score')->text
            ? [
                $e->attr('id'),
                map { $e->find("td.$_")->text }
                  (qw(tournament dateTime homeTeam score awayTeam prices))
            ]
            : ();
    });
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $football_matches;
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
    ['tn7gc635476', '', ' Mo 12Mar 2012 ', 'Arsenal',   'v', 'Newcastle', '  '],
    ['tn7gc649937', '', ' Tu 13Mar 2012 ', 'Liverpool', 'v', 'Everton',   '  '],
    ['tn7gc635681', '', ' Sa 17Mar 2012 ', 'Fulham',    'v', 'Swansea',   '  '],
    ['tn7gc635661', '', ' Sa 17Mar 2012 ', 'Wigan',     'v', 'West Brom', '  '],
    ['tn7gc635749', '', ' Su 18Mar 2012 ', 'Wolves',    'v', 'Man Utd',   '  '],
    ['tn7gc635556', '', ' Su 18Mar 2012 ', 'Newcastle', 'v', 'Norwich',   '  ']
];
```

What i would like to do is take each date, home team and away team and put them into normal variables/arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). Look for the part arrays-of-arrays and arrayref

Comment: +1 for perlref, -1 for perldsc. I feel strongly that dsc is a crutch, if you really understand perlref (and [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut), which I strongly recommend) then you don't need to follow the recipes in dsc.

Comment: i am pretty new to perl, is that $football_matches an array of arrays? As said before this answer was given to me, i don't 100% understand it as i was initially trying to do this using HTML::TokeParser.